# Kinvey shows 401 Unauthorized when I try to fetch data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, kinvey

I am using Kinvey with Backbone JS. When I do a fetch, with *Users*, Kinvey shows a 401 authorization error. I am not sure how to make the GET request but this is what I have tried so far:

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url: '//baas.kinvey.com/appdata/XXX/pplicants/YYY'
                });
```

Here XXX is my appkey and YYY is the _id of the data I am trying to fetch. pplicants.JSON is the name of the file I am trying to fetch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a cross-origin or same origin request?

Comment: Same origin, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at our users guide for backbone.js on the website?  You can find that here:  http://devcenter.kinvey.com/backbone/guides/users

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Hi. I did look at your users documentation. Calling the user.fetch function on  the active user returns a JSON containing the credentials of the user logged in. If I want to fetch the data from my collection, how do I go about it?